Non ASR & TTS but LID supported language by MMS
My native language is Mizo (https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/mms/misc/language_coverage_mms.html) and is included in the support for the language by MMS. I came to notice that MMS supported languages can be used in Coqui TTS (https://docs.coqui.ai/en/latest/index.html). However, the columns under ASR and TTS are not ticked in the supported language by MMS. Can I train this (Mizo) language in Coqui TTS? Or is it possible to include it in the English language dictionary (dataset) since Mizo uses a lot of English words?
I expected to make a working TTS with the opensource QoquiTTS. Can I train a new dataset to merged it with English dictionary (dataset).
